# Studying the fruitfly nervous system

Tags: neuroscience, drosophila

I'm studying Neuroscience and Fruit Flies are a pretty big deal but I don't know as much as I think I should about them.  Are there and comprehensive sources that I could read?

I'd like a review of all the important parts of the nervous system, where they are, what they do, and how they connect.

Comment: Drosophila by Ashburner (and others) is a standard drosophila book (found in many drosophila groups). Also check out resources like flybase, flyatlas, Bloomington drosophila stock center - they will often have some info. Not sure about neuroscience specific though

Comment: Please narrow this down a little, you could fill libraries with the sources of info on this little fly. What exactly are you after? Text books? Reviews? Original research? On what? Anatomy? Nervous system? Immune system? Sex determination?

Comment: I'd like a rundown of all the important ports of the nervous system, where they are, what they do, and how they connect.

Answer (score 1):

[Flybase](http://flybase.org/) is a generally useful source for Drosophila anatomy/physiology including the nervous system. From there I found [this link](http://www.ceolas.org/fly/) which has some neuroscience-specific info.